# Shopware 6 API This value should not be blank but it is not blank

Tags: shopware6-api

Trying to post Options and Option Groups to Shopware 6 sync Endpoint.

This is my upsert:

```
Array
(
    [upsert-property_group-0.03369400 1692787571#0] => Array
        (
            [action] => upsert
            [entity] => property_group
            [payload] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Shopware\Model\PropertyGroup Object
                        (
                            [id] => ef69a1f6b2a663ddd7b93310deb99923
                            [translations] => Array
                                (
                                    [de-DE] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Durchmesser
                                        )

                                    [en-GB] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Durchmesser
                                        )

                                )

                            [name] => Durchmesser
                            [displayType] => text
                            [sortingType] => alphanumeric
                            [customFields] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [options] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Shopware\Model\PropertyGroupOption Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 70a6095b1636bd3c154774ca0e9703c7
                                            [translations] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [de-DE] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => 450 mm
                                                        )

                                                    [en-GB] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => 450 mm
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [groupId] => ef69a1f6b2a663ddd7b93310deb99923
                                            [name] => 450 mm
                                            [customFields] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [group] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [media] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [productConfiguratorSettings] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [productOptions] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [productProperties] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The error is:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3",
      "status": "400",
      "detail": "This value should not be blank.",
      "template": "This value should not be blank.",
      "meta": {
        "parameters": {
          "{{ value }}": "null"
        }
      },
      "source": {
        "pointer": "\/upsert-property_group-0.03369400 1692787571#0\/0\/options\/0\/group\/translations\/2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b\/name"
      }
    }
}
```

How to solve this issue?

The ID `2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b` belongs to the language `en-GB`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with translations which is confusing unfortunately.

The problem in my data is `group` and `groupId` cannot exist simultaneously!

Does not work:

```
[groupId] => ef69a1f6b2a663ddd7b93310deb99923
[name] => 450 mm
[group] => Array ()
```

Does work:

```
[groupId] => ef69a1f6b2a663ddd7b93310deb99923
[name] => 450 mm
```

Should work:

```
[name] => 450 mm
[group] => Array (
    [id] => ef69a1f6b2a663ddd7b93310deb99923
)
```